# the google account image in one storyboard shows but didn't shows in another storyBoard

Tags: image, swift3, user-profile, googlesigninaccount

added google sign in in my app - I have different story board for iPhone 4or 4s and another for iPhone 5-5c-5s-se and another one for iPhone 6- 6s - 7 and another for iPhone 6plus-6splus-7plus 
my problem is that I can see the profile picture in all of the storyboards except storyboard for iPhone 6plus-6splus-7plus !

I received and error like this :

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-04-19 10:29:27.083269 Tipo[7327:3648156] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and here is my codes(the code is very long so I Just put the codes for Image)

```
if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.profile.hasImage 
{
    print("Account Has Image")

    print("\(personalImage)")

    ////Profile Photo

    let dimension = round(200 * UIScreen.main.scale)

    let pic = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.profile.imageURL(withDimension: UInt(dimension))

    self.personalImage?.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOf: pic!)! as Data)
}
```

**Remember That This code Is Working and I can see the profile image in simulator and iPhones like 6-6s-7-5-4 and the problem is just for iPhones plus size**

here is the picture of the error 
[image: error picture]